# VALIDATING textbox, combobox, radio button and date timepicker all at once in a single button in visual basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, validation

Good day! I have 10 textboxes, 4 radio buttons, 2 combo box, and 2 date time picker and 1 button in a single form. These objects are used to accept information from the users. My dillema is how to validate all these objects when i click the 1 button. Like for example i want to check if all of the objects have been filled up, if not it will show an error message specifying the object that the user failed to input. But if all the objects has been used/filled, it will transfer to another form and close the other one. Please Help me :(

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WinForms, you could add code to the button that goes something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim IsErrorPresent As Boolean = False ' We use this to flag whether ANY errors are present
    Dim ErrorDescription As String = "" ' We use this to build our error message to the user

    ' Validate first control
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
        IsErrorPresent = True ' We found an error!
        ErrorDescription += "The first textbox is empty. Please fill this out." & vbNewLine
    End If

    ' ... Do similar validation for other controls
    ' ... If any are found, we set IsErrorPresent to TRUE and add to our Error Description

    ' Now that we're done validating all of our controls, we either notify the user or process the valid data

    If IsErrorPresent = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is one or more errors with the information you supplied." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see below: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ErrorDescription, "Error In Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' We only get here if there is no error present in controls. Therefore, we can process validated information
    End If

End Sub
```

There may be more efficient ways to do this, but this should work.